# Ruby on Rails Single Sign On with multiple enterprise environments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, single-sign-on

Let me start off by saying that I'm not totally sure what I'm looking for. I'm hoping I can explain the situation I'm in, and that someone can point me in the right direction.

So here's what I'm up against. I want to build a ruby on rails application that will be hosted by oranization A on some domain organizationA.com. Then, multiple other organizations (X,Y,Z) will be accessing this tool from other domains (orgx.com, orgy.com, etc.). I do not know at this moment what form of authentication X,Y and Z will use, most likely it will be LDAP or native Windows, but the important thing is that it could be different from organization to organization.

In a situation like this, what is the best way (is there a way?) to allow the users at X,Y and Z to use the application using SSO. Are there any existing tools out there that you would recommend or have worked with? Is there a name for what I'm describing so I can do some better googling?

Any help is much appreciated.

## One Possibility

CASino - http://casino.rbcas.com/

Looks like this would be a separate server just for authentication, using the CAS authentication protocol, and could be used for multiple different types of authentication at different organizations. I'll have to check it out.

Answer (score 4):

I'm using CASino for our SSO Solution and it's really cool.

Comment: In casino, if the user is already authenticated on their domain, say using LDAP, and then they come to one of your applications using casino, do they have to enter their credentials, or do their credentials get passed through automatically so they can get straight into the application?

Comment: You need to use some sort of hidden iframe and enable the gateway option in CAS.

Answer (score 3):

[casino](https://github.com/rbCAS/CASino) and [rack-cas](https://github.com/biola/rack-cas) provide a good CAS server and client support for ruby based single sign on applications.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [rubycas-server](https://github.com/rubycas/rubycas-server) and [rubycas-client](https://github.com/rubycas/rubycas-client) if you are developing RoR applications

Im currently developing a enterprise system using the similar technology, My solution is using rubycas-server to manage user info and logins, and create separate user system base on ssoid of cas-server on each application sever to maintain the access level individually.